# Eclipse Project Expoloer Active Highlite Color

Tags: eclipse, colors, project-explorer

I'm trying to change the color of the Active selection in Project Explorer because its hard to see.  I've tried the options under Window | Preferences | General | Appearance and can change the tab active/inactive color but not the background of selected item in the project explorer.  It might be using the OS' (Win10) color settings but I'm not sure.  The active color is a light blue and the background is white which makes it hard to see.  I want to keep the white background.  I'm using Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17.0) out of the box and haven't downloaded or installed any themes. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe that is the OS "selection" colour rather than a colour chosen by Eclipse.

Comment: I was thinking that all so.  I tried to find it in Win10 but wasn't succesfull.

Comment: It looks like its taking the Explorer tree (left pane) colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Eclipse is taking Win10's Explorer Navigation pane or Tree colors for the Project Explorer.  I haven't found a way to change that but the link below suggested turning down the contrast and going from 85% to 75% made all the difference in the world.

[How to change highlighting color on folder selection windows 10 in file explorer?](http://%20https://superuser.com/questions/1287491/how-to-change-highlighting-color-on-folder-selection-windows-10-in-file-explorer)